# Reading Multiple tiff files in python from a folder

Tags: python, numpy

I have a folder containing 10K tiff files, how can i import all the files using python so that i can do some predictive modelling.

thanks
NK

Comment: maybe start with writing some code and sharing what you did?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following approach:

```
import os 
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

dirname = 'tiff_folder_path'
final = []
for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
    imarray = np.array(im)
    final.append(imarray)

final = np.asarray(final) # shape = (60000,28,28)
```

Comment: how do i stack/append the arrays for each file to make it a (60000,28,28) as i have 60K files of 28*28 pic. I tried the following line:
final = np.stack((final,imarray), axis = 0) and getting error  "all input arrays must have the same shape"

Comment: @user6658936 I have updated my answer as per your requirements.